# double gets rounded when returned

Tags: c, return, double, return-value

How do I return a double without getting [rounded](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ecfd74d963ff3632):

```
int function() {
    double d = 5.894; 
    printf("d=%f\n", d);
    return d;
}

int main() {
    double d = function();
    printf("d=%f\n", d);
    return 0;
}
```

This gives me

```
d=5.894000
d=5.000000
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: can someone explain the downvote?!

Comment: so yeah?! I am waiting for an explanation !

Comment: Just reviewed this question in triage, did not vote, but I have an explanation: many would consider this too simple to deserve a question on StackOverflow.

Comment: I know that but why? I did several C tutorials, none of them mentioned this. Also when I google this it's not very clear that you need this. Stackoverflow is also for beginners not only for advanced stuff. I did my research and spent enough time on that, I am sorry that I am just a beginner and didn't see that but that was my problems. Forums like these should be there for cases like that. The least thing I can expect is a rebuttal to that.

Comment: ok, so now, that I complained,  I see that I got one downvote removed. This seems to be completely random. I'll just go downvote whatever I want to, too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your function returns ٰ`int` it must return `double`

Change

```
int function()
```

to

```
double function()
```

Answer (score 1):

`iharob`'s answer is of course correct, but I think that it is also important to know how to avoid this kind of errors in the future.

I have also have not found any explicit reference of this behavior (implicit cast from a "large" numeric type to a "smaller" one), so I have asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35245625/c-implicit-numeric-type-demoting) about this.

Shortly put, **by providing the correct compilation warning flags, these errors can be spotted at compile time** (e.g. `-Wconversion`), as it's almost always a bug.

However, this behavior is by design, and as mentioned by Chris in a comment, sometimes it [might be useful](http://blog.llvm.org/2011/05/what-every-c-programmer-should-know.html) in terms of performance.